# Как подключать npm пакеты через gulp?

Tags: gulp, npm

Возможно не совсем корректно задаю вопрос.
Суть вот в чем:
Использую сборщик gulp. Rigger плагином собираю все js файлы таким образом:

```
//= jquery.js
//= bootstrap.js
//= ../../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js
```

Но подключать js или css файлы так не совсем удобно. Возможно есть более правильный и удобный путь решения этой проблемы?

Код задачи gulp-a:

```
gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src('src/js/main.js')
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('pages/js/'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Comment: В чем собственно неудобство?

Comment: В указании пути к файлам вместо простого `require('bootstrap-select.js');`

Comment: Т.е. что-то вроде webpack-а вы хотите? (чтобы по этим require склеивался один js)

Comment: Возможно, посмотрю не излишне ли мне использовать webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сразу указать путь ко всем файлам в папке JS, не указывая каждый файл отдельно. В данном примере собираю все файлы в единый `script.js` и записываю результат в `public`:

```
gulp.task('js:build', function(){
    gulp.src('./js/**/*')
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
});
```